# parse complex xml with php simple xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to parse (little critical) xml using php simplexml...But i can aither get attribute or either value...m not able to parse this XML properly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Leads/getMyRecords">
    <result>
        <Leads>
            <row no="1">
                <FL val="LEADID">418176000000051001</FL>
                <FL val="SMOWNERID">418176000000047003</FL>
                <FL val="Lead Owner"><![CDATA[Amit Patil]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Company"><![CDATA[demo Company]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="First Name"><![CDATA[Test]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Last Name"><![CDATA[Demo]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Designation"><![CDATA[Tesing Lead]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="No of Employees"><![CDATA[0]]>
                </FL>
```

And this is what i am soo far

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
if($xml != null){
   foreach($xml->result->Leads->row as $key=>$row){
       foreach($row->FL as $key=>$val){
           echo $val.",";
       }
   }
}
```

How can i parse this XML using simplexml or may be something else ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

val is an attributeof FL, not the content... so I'm not sure what you're trying to retrieve when you use the ambiguously named $val

As the code you have should already display the content of each element: to retrieve the attributes, use

```
foreach($xml->result->Leads->row as $key=>$row){
    foreach($row->FL as $key => $value){
        echo $value['val']." => ";
        echo $value."<br />";
    }
}
```

From your snippet of XML, this gives:

```
LEADID => 418176000000051001
SMOWNERID => 418176000000047003
Lead Owner => Amit Patil 
Company => demo Company 
First Name => Test 
Last Name => Demo 
Designation => Tesing Lead 
No of Employees => 0
```

Comment: I was working on it for 2-3 hours and gone deeeep inside and forgot to think simple...neither even noticed that it should work if i think like ita an array like u have done it :) :) i solved it using this     foreach($row->FL as $val) $val->attributes()."=".$val;

Comment: Thank u sooo much for this simple solution and for bringing me back to normal :) :) :)

Comment: On a side note, use strval($value) if you wish to store the string value of $value, since $value is actually a simple xml object.